# Smartface Android Header Logo

Tags: smartface.io

Can I change [this logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyzlA.jpg) to show slider on android? I tried

```
this.actionbar.logo = "img_source";
```

in HeaderBar script page, but it didn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct property is icon ;

```
this.actionBar.icon = 'img_source';
```

You can read more about actionBar from http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/controls/actionbar/